# search for sentences that contains a few keywords (that is not in proper order)

Tags: terminal

Is there script or function for vim to do search of words that is not in proper location (sorry, i don't know how to put it in question) ?

Example:
This is a vim user who like the functionality which is pure manual power.

Question:
I want to search a sentence which contains words "power, vim , functionality".

I have to remember the order of the keywords to do search:

```
/vim.*functionality.*power
```

Only in this way, the result will be yielded. Which is not useful.

But if i don't remember the arrangement of those keywords..
Hence when i do a search :

```
/power.*vim.*functionality
```

It will not give me the result i wanted.

What is the solution ?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a branch syntax `\&`,

```
/.*power\&.*vim\&.*functionality
```

would find all lines containing all of these three words

Note that the `.*` are necessary as branch attempts to match all parts at the same location.

Comment: I just want to know for the sake of more diversity, otherwise i can use :LogiPat to do the search .

Comment: edited to clarify this is a search pattern

Comment: Somehow i manage to follow your syntax and get it. Thx

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent use case for the LogiPat built-in plugin. LogiPat builds regular expressions using boolean logic.

In your particular example, run:

```
:LogiPat "power"&"vim"&"functionality"
```

This uses `search()` internally. If you want to highlight your matches, type `//` as usual.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the only solution, i tried and it works too:

```
/word3\|word1\|word2
```

It will highlight the line with the words even when in random order.

Comment: this is any of not all of