# How can I strip footnotes using :global?

Tags: global-command

I have a very large table covering many pages in a document. The same footnote appears under the table on every page and I want to strip the entire document of these lines so I'm left only with the table. Imagine there are 3 footnotes like this:

```
This is a footnote
Another footnote
Yet another footnote
```

It seems I can delete the first footnote with `:g/^T/d`, and delete the 2nd with `:g/^A/d`, etc. But is there some way to tell vim to delete any line starting with `T` or `A` or `Y` in a single command?

It might seem unwise to run the command above over the entire document but the table is full of numbers and I know there are no other lines beginning with a letter aside from those in the footnote.

I checked the vim book by Robbins, Hannab & Lamb and couldnt see that it was possible. Can I assume an experienced vim user would simply type `:` and then use the arrow keys to recall the previous command and change the one letter, and repeat this for the number of lines in the footnote?

Comment: To answer the last question, I highly doubt an experienced vim user would use `:<up>` to change a single letter for every single footnote line :) In fact, if you know they all have a format like `1. `, you can do something like `:global/^\d\. /delete`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer, p75 Robbins, Hannab & Lamb: `[]` means "match any one of the characters enclosed between brackets."

So I would do:

```
:g/^[TAY]/d
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally, see `:help {pattern}`. For more complex patterns, you might want alternations (`/^\(T\|A\|Y\)/`) or [concats](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37471/10604).

Comment: thanks! i have some vim reading to do :)